# when magento sql is executed while using collection

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento collection. I have a question about a filter.
If I execute following PHP code, when does SQL get executed?

```
$xxx_collection = Mage::getModel('modulename/xxx')->getCollection();
$xxx_collection->getSelect()->limit($limit, $offset);
$xxx_collection->addFieldToFilter('user', $customerData->getId())->addFieldToFilter('xxx_id', 0);
```

The last line(filter code) will execute SQL? 
What about the second (limit code) line?
If I don't use third line(addFieldToFilter), then the second line will execute SQL?

I am asking this question because I don't want my Magento to execute SQL twice. it will make overhead.

Comment: getSelect() will execute your sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xxx_collection->getSelect()->limit($limit, $offset);
```

The code in line 2 will not execute query. Collection object executes query only when its `load()` function is called. You can call load function just after preparing collection query or it will call internally load function when you use collection object in iterator function like in `foreach` loop.

Your code is fine, and not executing it twice.

Comment: I don't know your answer is correct or not, because i'm beginner magento developer.
But your answer looks much reliable.